# Read RFID tag that is already next to the phone before my app started

Tags: android, nfc

I wrote a small program that is scaning for RFID Tag, it works fine. But I have a case that I need to read an RFID tag that is already next to my phone before my app started.

Is there a way that can tell Android to scan again for a nearby RFID/NFC tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, The Tag is 'Discovered' when it moves into range of the device NFC aerial.  You could however utilise the 'Background Dispatch' facility, whereby you define your filters for NFC intents in your Activity definition in your Manifest, as described in the Android documentation for NFC Basics.  This way, when you place the Tag near to your device it will read the Tag and start your application at the defined Activity.

Comment: Or use an Android Application Record for Android version >= 4.0